# Count words of a body field using PHP views field

Tags: 7, views

I'm looking for a way to count the amount of words in my body fields, using Views PHP. I am totally new to PHP and this looks so easy, but I must be missing something.

So I have a View for Content, containing a body field (hide display, HTML trimmed) and a Global: PHP field.

I have this in my "Value Code"-field inside the Global: PHP field settings:

```
$count = print $row->body;
$result = str_word_count("$count");
```

And this in my Output:

```
<?php echo $result ?>
```

Seems I must be missing something, but I get no error, nor any result. Just nothing happens.

Comment: Try this without $count var `$result = str_word_count($row->body);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but makes no difference. When looking in my dblog, I get this statement: `Notice: Undefined variable: result in __lambda_func() (line 1 of /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/sites/all/modules/views_php/plugins/views/views_php_handler_field.inc(202) : runtime-created function).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long research, I stumbled at this [issue post](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php/issues/1061388). It seems that field data are not present in the result set of Views PHP, so instead of `print $row->body`I needed to use `print $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['nl'][0]['value']` to access the data.  This solved my problem.